# How can I import data from a CSV file into lists of strings and lists of integers, at the same time?

Tags: python, string, list, integer

So far I have the code I need to open a CSV file and import the data contained into several lists. However, these are all lists of strings, and I need some as lists of strings and others as lists of integers.

So far I have the following code to import my data into a series of lists.

```py
filename = open('/path/to/myfile.csv', 'r')
file = csv.DictReader(filename)

Sample_ID = []
Well = []
DNA_vol =[]
ddH2O_vol = []

for col in file:
    Sample_ID.append(col['Sample_ID'])
    Well.append(col['Well'])
    DNA_vol.append(col['DNA_vol'])
    ddH2O_vol.append(col['ddH2O_vol'])
```

With lists showing as below:

```py
Well = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']
DNA_vol = ['2', '4', '6', '8', '10', '1', '2', '4', '8', '10']
```

Sample_ID and Well show as intended, as a list of strings. However I need DNA_vol and ddH2O_vol to be a list of integers instead for my code to work as intended.

I have tried including an int() function in various places at the appending section and afterwards, but no luck.

How can I change the DNA_vol.append... and ddH2O_vol.append... lines to produce lists of integers?

Other similar questions open the file using

```
open with
```

instead, and so these solutions do not help my specific case.

Many thanks

Comment: what is the error when you do `DNA_vol.append(int(col['DNA_vol']))`, that should do your work if all strings can be convert to integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a set of strings to integers using the `list` and `map` functions as below:

```
DNA_vol_as_int = list(map(int, DNA_vol))
print(DNA_vol_as_int)
```

See [`map()` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list)

Comment: I managed to get it working using:

DNA_vol.append(int(col['DNA_vol']))

But didnt have any success with your option - TypeError: 'list' object not callable.

Do you know whats causing this?

Thanks :)

Comment: @aLiveDiatribe You need to show the actual code that fails. When I tried with your data and the above two lines I got a list of all the values as integers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that all the values in `DNA_vol` and `ddH2O_vol` must be integer. If not put a try except block to handle non-integer situations.

```py
filename = open('/path/to/myfile.csv', 'r')
file = csv.DictReader(filename)

Sample_ID = []
Well = []
DNA_vol =[]
ddH2O_vol = []

for col in file:
    Sample_ID.append(col['Sample_ID'])
    Well.append(col['Well'])
    try:
        DNA_vol.append(int(col['DNA_vol']))
    except ValueError:
        DNA_vol.append(0)
    try:
        ddH2O_vol.append(int(col['ddH2O_vol']))
    except ValueError:
        ddH2O_vol.append(0)
```

Since you have not shared the csv sample file or any additional information, in this code it is assumed that if there are any exceptions, the value is set to 0 [or, 0 is appended]

Comment: Thanks this one helped! I'm sure I tried simply DNA_vol.append(int(col['DNA_vol'])) before but it must have not worked for some other reason. Maybe I gave up on that too soon.

Now that I've tried it, it actually seems I don't need the except ValueError - is this for when the CSV cell is blank?

Comment: The ValueException occurs when you cannot convert a string into an integer using int() because it may be a non-numeric string or an empty string. You might also get a TypeError if it gets a None value.

Answer (score 0):

Using the dataclasses built-in you can use the annotations for the fields to set the type-conversion. The post_init will handle the conversion based on the type-hints.

```
import csv
import io # only for the csv_data
import dataclasses
from dataclasses import dataclass

csv_data = '''\
"Sample_ID","Well","DNA_vol","ddH2O_vol"
sample_0,A1,2,3
sample_1,A2,4,5\
'''

@dataclass
class Row:
    Sample_ID: str
    Well: str
    DNA_vol: int
    ddH2O_vol: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        # use the field's typehint to convert the string to that type
        for field in dataclasses.fields(self):
            value = getattr(self, field.name)
            setattr(self, field.name, field.type(value))

reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(csv_data))  # I used the string to load in, here you can use your file

rows = []
for row in reader:
    rows.append(Row(**row))

print([row.Sample_ID for row in rows])
print([row.DNA_vol for row in rows])
```

## Outputs:

```
['sample_0', 'sample_1']
[2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so a few things here:

1. Using `with open(...) as f` is equivalent to `f = open(...)` and closing the file handle at the end of the with block
2. You're not closing your file handle, so consider either doing so after you're done reading it, or using a `with` block
3. You're reading a plaintext file, so naturally everything coming in is being parsed as text. The documentation for `csv` doesn't make any mention of the `int` type either. So you'll have to parse it yourself!
4. The name `col` is misleading, considering you're parsing the file row-by-row (or line-by-line, which is the same thing for CSVs)

The one line edit to just have your `DNA_vol` values as `int`s is simply:

```py
DNA_vol.append(int(col['DNA_vol']))
```

---

This wouldn't be SO, however, if we weren't here to be informative for future reference and people seeking advice in the future.

```py
import csv
import os

# Either use `with open(...) as ..:` here or close the file at the end
file_obj = open('/path/to/my/file.csv', 'r')
    # Add a level of indentation to **ALL** below code if you're using a `with` block!
file = csv.DictReader(file_obj)
# Get your lists set up
sample_ID = []
well = []
DNA_vol = []
ddH2O = []
# Loop over the list of dicts
for row in file:
    sample_ID.append(line['Sample_ID'])
    well.append(line['Well'])
    # Check if the other two fields are purely numeric values and, if so, parse them as ints.
    # replace with `isdecimal` and `float` if the numbers might not be just ints
    # Defaults to 0 for numeric values, but feel free to pick any other number
    # if your dataset has a strict minimum or something
    DNA_vol.append(if line['DNA_vol'].isdigit() int(line['DNA_vol']) else 0)
    ddH2O.append(if line['ddH2O_vol'].isdigit() int(line['ddH2O_vol']) else 0)
# That's all there's to it! Now if you used a with block, you don't need the next line:
os.close(file_obj) # Don't leak the file descriptor
# When using the `open` builtin, and you're not passing a custom opener, `os.open` is the default
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use pandas `read_csv()` method

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    "/path/to/myfile.csv", 
    names=["Sample_ID", "Well", "DNA_vol", "ddH2O_vol"], 
    dtype={"Sample_ID": str, "Well": str, "DNA_vol": int, "ddH2O_vol": int}
)
```

now you have a dataframe `df` containing your data that should be very easy to work with.

Comment: this requires a 3rd party module to be installed which might not be available or introduces dependencies

Comment: Thanks, but I am working with robotics that I don't think allow packages like pandas to be installed. From what I have seen already that package would make things much easier tho :L